# Strip domain name from url (string)

Tags: jquery, string

I'm accessing the stylesheet collection like this:

```
var css = document.styleSheets[0];
```

It returns eg. `http://www.mydomain.com/css/main.css`

Question: how can I strip the domain name to just get `/css/main.css` ?

Comment: See this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418050/string-strip-for-javascript

Comment: i forgot to mention that the domain name should be variable - so no replacing.

Comment: See my new answer that uses a regular expression, which will work with any domain name.

Comment: Stop writing tags in titles please. You've been here almost two years!

Answer (score 8):

This regular expression should do the trick. It will replace any domain name found with an empty string. Also supports https://

```
//css is currently equal to http://www.mydomain.com/css/main.css    
css = css.replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/i, "");
```

This will return `/css/main.css`

Comment: Simple and clean, for global flag add use it like css.replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/ig, "");
@Erikk-ross, can you please add http and global support to it?

Comment: I would do `css = css.replace(/(https?:)?\/\/[^\/]+/i, "");`, because a `//` prefix means use protocol-relative URL (the browser decides whether to use HTTP or HTTPS according to the current used protocol of the main page).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trick, by creating a `<a>`-element, then setting the string to the href of that `<a>`-element and then you have a [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) you can get the pathname from.

You could either add a method to the String prototype:

```
String.prototype.toLocation = function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = this;
    return a;
};
```

and use it like this:
    `css.toLocation().pathname`

or make it a function:

```
function toLocation(url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a;
};
```

and use it like this:
    `toLocation(css).pathname`

both of these will output: `"/css/main.css"`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
css = document.styleSheets[0];
cssAry = css.split('/');

domain = cssAry[2];
path = '/' + cssAry[3] + '/' + cssAry[4];
```

This technically gives you your domain and path.

Answer (score 0):

`URL.replace(/\S{0,6}\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]*\//, '')` strips the domain part identified by:

- 0-6 non-whitespace chars at the beginning ..
- .. followed by '//' ..
- .. followed by any numbers, letters, dots, hyphens and underscores until a slash comes

```js
let URL = 'http://www.example.com/css/main.css'
document.write (URL.replace(/\S{0,6}\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]*/, '') +'<br>')

URL = 'upTo5://www.example.com/css/main.css'
document.write (URL.replace(/\S{0,6}\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]*/, '') +'<br>')

URL = 'http://a-zA-Z0-9-_.upToSlash/css/main.css'
document.write (URL.replace(/\S{0,6}\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]*/, '') +'<br>')

URL = '//www.example.com/css/main.css'
document.write (URL.replace(/\S{0,6}\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]*/, '') +'<br>')
//Protocol, e.g. 'http' may be omitted in cases, where it default automatically.
//Commonly in links, where the URL is known, but SSL/TLS support of target site is not.
```

Answer (score -3):

```
css = css.replace('http://www.mydomain.com', '');
```