# How to get the domain name out of a string in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like this

```
http://www.example.com/xyz/filename.php
```

Now I just want to get the string `http://www.example.com/` how can I do this ?

I know this is a simple question but I have tried its not working

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried and what did not work? Did you check that link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597049/strip-domain-name-from-url-string

Comment: duplicate --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815559/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url-using-jquery

Comment: Webkit-based browsers and Firefox as of version 21 know window.location.origin. To target all browsers, I use the following **if (!window.location.origin)
     window.location.origin = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var $url = 'http://www.example.com/css/filename.php';

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = $url;

var $finalUrl = a.protocol + '//' + a.hostname + '/';
```

Comment: In his question he added an `/` to his desired result. So before the last `;` add `+ '/'`.

Comment: Yes, i updated Benno Zeeman