# Trimming whitespace from the END of a string only, with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

I know of the jQuery $.trim() function, but what I need is a way to trim whitespace from the END of a string only, and NOT the beginning too.

So

```
  str ="     this is a string     ";
```

would become

```
  str ="     this is a string";
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
str = str.replace(/\s*$/,"");
```

It says replace all whitespace at the end of the string with an empty string.

Breakdown:

- `\s*` : Any number of spaces
- `$` : The end of the string

More on regular expressions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: It removes new lines as well

Answer (score 2):

For some browsers you can use:
`str = str.trimRight();`
or
`str = str.trimEnd();`

If you want total browser coverage, use regex.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimEnd