# How to eliminate white-space at the beginning and at the end of a javascript string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, removing-whitespace

I need, as title explains, to **eliminate white space** at the beginning and at the end of a javascript string **using regex** and/or/with some js function.
This is the string that I have to clean:

> "
>   
>   
>   a word
>   
>   
>   another word
>   
>   
>   
>   "

That is the target I want to reach:

> "a word
>   
>   
>   
>   another word"

Best regards

Comment: `string.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s)+/g, '')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418050/string-strip-for-javascript

Comment: `.replace(/^\n+|\n+$/g, '')`